# I have a `lxml` installed and I can not find it

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I had to parse xml and tried to install and use the library. I installed it on my `datalab notebook` as follows.

```
!pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But when I try to use it, I get an error.

```
FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Everything is used as a `datalab`. Is it a problem like environment variables?

thanks.

### Update

Is it ok to show another sample? (in `datalab notebook`)

```
!pip install scikit-learn==0.18.1
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn==0.18.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

import sklearn
print ("scikit-learn version: {}". format(sklearn.__version__))
scikit-learn version: 0.17.1

print(sklearn.__path__)
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn']
```

It probably seems to refer to the default environment variable without reading the installed path. What do you think?

### solution

[`Restart Service`](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) has been fixed. thanks @yelsayed @Ethan_kim

Comment: It's working fine for me. What's the code causing the error message?

Comment: @yelsayed It's hard to show the code and I have another sample in the text, can you take a look?

Comment: Looks to me like you have two versions of the pip package installed? When you install, use the upgrade option: `!pip install -U <package>`, this way you can explicitly tell python to use a specific version. Does this fix the issue?

Comment: The same is true for update packages using the options you have given.(`!pip install -U sklearn`) I do not know why the old version is still used because the path of the updated package is the same as the imported path.